# Requesting permissions without using runtime permissions

Tags: android, permissions

Throughout my app I request permissions runtime, but for the READ_SMS permission, I would like to have that permission enabled on download from playstore. How can I request permissions from play store install instead of at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  It used to be that all permissions were granted at install time.  Now, important permissions like that can only be granted at runtime.  This is to improve the user's security, allow them to prevent apps from accessing data they don't want to share without realizing it, and allow them to revoke permissions when no longer applicable.